# How Could I Create a Website That Sends User Data to Me?

Tags: javascript, html

I just started working on a chatbot. I want to be able to have a website that people can visit to have a conversation with the chatbot prototype, and have the statements that people type be sent to me. The reason I want to do this is so I can make the chatbot complex and able to respond to many statements.

Comment: have a look at http://socket.io and http://google.it !

Answer (score 0):

Since you marked the question with html, i am assuming that the chatbot is running on a webpage.
 Firstly, as the comment already mentioned, socket.io is a good way to use for your chatbot.
 If you don't want to use third party engine, using javascript alone is almost impossible for you to collect data to server-side since js itself is a client-sided language, so in my own opinion, i would say the using PHP, ASP or other kind of server-sided language

Comment: Thank you, @Dreamer. Do you have a suggestion on a tutorial I could use to find out how to send user data to me with node.js?